# how to play videos when we scroll like vine and insatagram?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, instagram, vine

In My app,I have play videos based on the visibility of the video when we scroll like vine and Instagram.When loading all the data at a once causes out of memory exception.So I have to play video like vine and instagram

Thanks to All.

Comment: please check the following link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/6832598#6832598][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/6832598#6832598

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BackBar" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#D6DEAA">
  <Button android:id="@+id/BackButton" android:layout_gravity="left" android:text="@string/BackButtonText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
  </LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentVideo" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="30px" android:paddingTop="15px" android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/learn_hiv_blck1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/learn_hiv_blck1" android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="italic" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_gravity="left" /> 
  <TextView android:id="@+id/learn_hiv_blck2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="15px" android:text="@string/learn_hiv_blck2" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_gravity="left" /> 
  <TextView android:id="@+id/learn_hiv_blck3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="15px" android:text="@string/learn_hiv_blck3" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_gravity="left" /> 
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView" android:layout_width="283dip" android:layout_height="183dip" android:background:"#0000"/> 
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentVideo" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="30px" android:paddingTop="15px" android:paddingBottom="40dip" android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/learn_hiv_blck4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/learn_hiv_blck4" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_gravity="left" /> 
  <VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView1" android:layout_width="280dip" android:layout_height="190dip" android:visibility="gone" /> 
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```