# YouTubePlayerView on a ScrollView

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-scrollview, android-youtube-api

First, I'd like to point out that there seems to be a limitation in Android in which having a `SurfaceView` on a `ScrollView` doesn't work as you would expect. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312585/androidvideoview-inside-a-scrollview)
(`VideoView` uses a `SurfaceView` internally so it has this problem). But there seems to be a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem/6832598#6832598) for `VideoView` which worked for me.

Now, I also want to use the new [YouTube API for Android](https://www.google.com.uy/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/&ei=Q9daUdDwAsiZ0QGxvYHgAw&usg=AFQjCNFS3VWPxCAuZrYGTHSi3AuWn0ul4w&bvm=bv.44442042,d.eWU) to display embedded YouTube videos on our Android app. The `YouTubePlayerView` which implements the embedded video player also presents the problem mentioned above since it uses a SurfaceView as shown below in the hierarchy viewer.

[image: SurfaceView on the YouTubePlayerView]

I haven't been able to find a workaround for this problem. Having a `YouTubePlayerView` on a `ScrollView` is a fairly common use case for our app (and probably for many others too). I would appreciate any comments on this.

Comment: I am trying for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would like this functionality too, but alas, it seems it is still being implemented by Google.

See here:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4514

The solution should be to use a `TextureView` which [supports playing videos within a `ScrollView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview).  Hopefully YouTube API supports this soon.