# Videoview in scrollview issue

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-scrollview

I have googled a lot to solve this issue but it doesn't works in any case. Have tried everything as mentioned in [Android::VideoView inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312585/androidvideoview-inside-a-scrollview) and [Android Scrollview having videoview is giving problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896921/android-scrollview-having-videoview-is-giving-problem).

The problem is when i put the video view in scrollview it doesn't works, but when remove the scrollview it works absolutely fine.

Here is the example code :

```
// xml file
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="start" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_video" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java code, `MainActivity` class

```
package com.practice.videoviewexample;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView videoView_exhibit;
    private Button btnVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView_exhibit = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_1);
        btnVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_video);


        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.abc);
        videoView_exhibit.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView_exhibit.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help? Thanx in advance!

Comment: You're describing the problem and you're also mentioning that this is a technical constraint that we all are aware of. So don't put the ViewView in the ScrollView ...

Comment: I expect any alternatives for the problem. I have a requirement to show a video view at the bottom of scrollview.

Comment: Try to use the `TextureView` (API level 14 upwards). Haven't used it before, but Romain Guy says it's a valid alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known limitation of VideoView.
Check this : [VideoView inside ScrollView](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37229)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. But any alternative for that?

Comment: I dont think so, there is any other way. :(

Comment: create custom videoview and set the size(setDimensions(w,h)) at runtime will solved the problem.
Please refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video/4452597#4452597

Answer (score 2):

By changing VideoView attributes android:layout_width and android:layout_height to fixed dp size (100dp) VideoView shown up.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding :

```
 android:background="#0000"
```

to the videoView

Answer (score 0):

I didn't managed to get the VideoView working inside a ScrollView, but instead **in some cases** it is possible to scale the VideoView depending on the available vertical space by setting the VideoView's size attributes to:

```
<VideoView
            android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

This will scale the VideoView and keep the aspect ratio of the video.