# Android: Moving background image while navigating through five home screen views

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I want to Move background image while navigating through 5 home screen Views.
just like when we select an image from gallery and set as wallpaper and then it scrolls with the change of home screen view(offset).

```
      SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {

                drawCircles(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
```

the draw function is

```
{
    private void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        DisplayMetrics metdisplayMatrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getMetrics(metdisplayMatrics);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.drawColor(0xff000000);
            mRecscreenRectangleFrame = new Rect(0, 0,  (int) (metdisplayMatrics.widthPixels*2.0), metdisplayMatrics.heightPixels);
            photo1= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
            canvas.drawBitmap(photo1, null,mRecscreenRectangleFrame, paint);
            photo1.recycle();
            System.gc();
}
```

Comment: see my edited question , I want to create a static wallpaper. with Moving background image while navigating through five home screen views

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096618/android-surfaceview-scrolling

Comment: I am in wallpapers service...