# ScrollView with custom view wont scroll - android?

Tags: java, android, view, scrollview

Tried to build and add a customview on a ScrollView. But it wont Scroll.

While overriding  onMeasure - it's not recognized.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

</ScrollView>
//tried above making as child.
```

Code:

```
ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
//LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.line);

myView gw = new myView(this,bitmap);
// ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(480,800);
scrollView.addView(gw);
scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
```

myView Class draws bitmap using this code:

```
public class myView extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    public myView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {

        super(context);

        holder = getHolder();

        this.bitmap = bitmap;

 }
         .....

    @Override

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.draw(canvas);

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 10, 20, null);


        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);


        canvas.drawText("Second floor", x, y + 600, paint1);

        Log.d("test", "drawing....");


    }
```

View draws but wont scroll.
How to make it scroll?

Comment: you have not set width and height to the view. Scroll view works when the view is out of view(out of the screen that makes scorlling enable)

Comment: The custom view draws a huge image which is out of the sceen measure.

Comment: can you Put code for Custom View

Comment: can you please share where it is drawing that huge image?

Comment: edited. The image size is 1800px X 1080px. screensize is 1280 x 720 px.

Comment: Does this has effect on implementing onTouchListener?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your view with some ViewGroup like LinearLayout or FrameLayout:

```
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
linear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linear.setOrientation(1);
scrollView.addView(linear);

myView gw = new myView(this,bitmap);
linear.addView(gw );
```

EDIT:

From your code I see that you are using SurfaceView. SurfaceView is very different and does not support scrolling from ScrollView. You can change the view from SurfaceView to something else or add:

```
implements View.OnTouchListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

and implement scrolling by yourself.

See: [Android SurfaceView scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096618/android-surfaceview-scrolling/2216788)

Comment: I tried this but doesn't scroll. Also tried this using XML. but this canvas object wont scroll.

Comment: It has this callback added to holder. Should I implement it? -  holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {...}

Comment: Yes exactly - as described in the quoted answer.

Comment: Tested with this, drawing the view and seeing the half image but still not scrolling. However onTouchListener working on this since begining.

Comment: Sorry to say but using this solution not working scroll is just your implementation fault since you have to provide it by yourself. Linked question shows exactly how to do this. Are you sure you've done everything correctly?

Comment: I see the linked question. Its pointing a different approach. which is picking up x,y manually.